# Hibernate size of data

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

i need to receive the size of data (in byte) from a postgres database.
Postgres has this method called: octet_length what is exactly doing what i want. 
But i can't find a way to get the same from Hibernate. 
So is it possible to receive these information from Hibernate?

Comment: Use a `NativeQuery`?

Comment: I thought there is maybe a hibernate solution for this. But if not, i will use the NativeQuery. Thx

Comment: don't think anything is available with hibernate.  field.length for byte array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Hibernate register the octet_length function into this dialect.

For example in PostgreSQL8Dialect.java  we can see:

```
registerFunction( "octet_length", new StandardSQLFunction("octet_length", Hibernate.LONG) );
```

So you can use

```
Projections.SqlFunction
```

in your code